# Python pyplot.hist ignores range if it is larger than dataset?

Tags: python, matplotlib, range

I am making histograms for a variety of datasets and want them all to use the same bins so that they are easily comparable. It seems that if the bin distribution is much large than the dataset, however, hist ignores the range and makes a smaller one. For example:

```
x=[random.randrange(1,10) for _ in xrange(1000)]

plt.hist(x, 50, range=[0, 100])
plt.show()
```

I only get the 5 bins from 0-10 instead of 50 from 0-100. I assume I am missing some obvious to everyone else parameter?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
In [37]: plt.hist(x, 50, range=[0,100])
Out[37]:
(array([ 103.,  228.,  233.,  228.,  208.,    0.,    0.,    0.,    0.,
           0.,    0.,    0.,    0.,    0.,    0.,    0.,    0.,    0.,
           0.,    0.,    0.,    0.,    0.,    0.,    0.,    0.,    0.,
           0.,    0.,    0.,    0.,    0.,    0.,    0.,    0.,    0.,
           0.,    0.,    0.,    0.,    0.,    0.,    0.,    0.,    0.,
           0.,    0.,    0.,    0.,    0.]),
 array([   0.,    2.,    4.,    6.,    8.,   10.,   12.,   14.,   16.,
          18.,   20.,   22.,   24.,   26.,   28.,   30.,   32.,   34.,
          36.,   38.,   40.,   42.,   44.,   46.,   48.,   50.,   52.,
          54.,   56.,   58.,   60.,   62.,   64.,   66.,   68.,   70.,
          72.,   74.,   76.,   78.,   80.,   82.,   84.,   86.,   88.,
          90.,   92.,   94.,   96.,   98.,  100.]),
 <a list of 50 Patch objects>)
```

the function returns the bins and the patches. As you can see here, there are in fact 50 bins there. matplotlib just chooses to clip the figure off where there is no more data.

Comment: Hmm.. So how can I tell it to not do that clipping?

Comment: OK, so it looks like setting the autoscale to false did not fix it, but setting the x range seemed to work.